# Why Scipy does not have geom.fit but has norm.fit?

Tags: probability, scipy

This is a newbie question.

I see that Scipy can estimate the two norms (mean and variance) of a normal distribution using sample data. That's done using the `scipy.stats.norm.fit` function. However, it seems like it cannot do the same for a geometric distribution, as `scipy.stats.geom.fit` is not a thing. Why is that?

What am I supposed to use to fit data through a geometric random variable in Scipy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scipy.stats.mean` will give you the mean $\bar X$. Depending on [which definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) of the geometric distribution you use, the parameter $p$ is estimated either by $1/\bar X$ or $1/(1+\bar X)$

Comment: That makes sense. Although, I couldn't find `scipy.stats.mean`. I used `scipy.stats.tmean` instead.